# Can I restore stack with add sp etc

Tags: c, assembly, stack

In my program I am pushing some values on the stack

```
for (i=0;i<i2;i++)
    { 
    _asm
       {  
       mov eax,i   // i here is an (int)
       push eax 
       }
    }
```

Then later when I'm done i restore the stack like this:

```
for (i=0;i<i2;i++)
    { 
    _asm
       {  
       pop eax  // eax in not used later
       }
    }
```

Works ok but probably wasting cycles.
Is it ok to restore the stack like this:

```
i=i2*sizeof(int);
_asm
   {  
   add sp,i
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

That will work provided the arithmetic is done correctly.  My usual bug is being off-by-one on such things.

You might also have a look at the [`enter`](http://www.piclist.com/techref/intel/x86/inst/enters.htm) and [`leave`](http://www.piclist.com/techref/intel/x86/inst/leave.htm) instructions to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if it works, but it looks like that last one could be done with just a `LEA ESP, [ESP+4*EAX]`. Saves an additional multiply and leaves your condition flags untouched.